# Plot 3D Surface from 2D lines in MatPlotLib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bunch of data which I am able to generate discrete 3D curves for, when plotted I just get a bunch of 2D lines at each z value, as in curve 1 (a) and (b), I want to be able to plot the surface that the 2D lines trace out, similar to what I did in curve 1 (a+b) but I want to plot the full surface, instead of the grid that is traced out and maybe add a color gradient to visualize the depth of each curve. Is this possible? I do not have data points inbetween z values, only for each discrete value of z.

Curve 1 (a) and Curve 1(b) are both generated from exactly the same discrete x y and z values, in my code, I had to break it up into a horizontal and vertical portion, is there a way to plot the grid or surface without having to split it up like this?

For each z value in z_vals, I have a corresponding plot (x,y) held in (zarr[:,0],zarr[:,1]).

[image]

Additionally, I want to be able to plot an additional curve as in curve 2, but only when a radio button is pressed, or just an animation between curve 1 and curve 2, but on the same plot.

This is my code so far,

```
z_htxt = np.array(['z_h_0_05','z_h_0_06','z_h_0_07','z_h_0_08','z_h_0_09','z_h_0_1','z_h_0_125','z_h_0_15','z_h_0_175','z_h_0_2','z_h_0_225','z_h_0_25','z_h_0_275','z_h_0_3','z_h_0_325','z_h_0_35','z_h_0_375','z_h_0_4','z_h_0_45','z_h_0_5','z_h_0_55','z_h_0_6','z_h_0_65','z_h_0_7','z_h_0_75','z_h_0_8','z_h_0_85','z_h_0_9','z_h_0_93'])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(221,projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222,projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223,projection='3d')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224,projection='3d')
z_vals = np.array([.05,.06,.07,.08,.09,.1,.125,.15,.175,.2,.225,.25,.275,.3,.325,.35,.375,.4,.45,.5,.55,.6,.65,.7,.75,.8,.85,.9,.93])
zarr = np.zeros([z_htxt.size,2,30])

for i in range(z_htxt.size):
    ltxt = z_htxt[i]+'_Q2_100.txt'
    zarr[i] = np.loadtxt(ltxt)
    ax2.plot(zarr[i,0],zarr[i,1],zs=z_vals[i],zdir='z',c='b')
    ax3.plot(zarr[i,0],zarr[i,1],zs=z_vals[i],zdir='z',c='b')
ax.plot(zarr[:,0],zarr[:,1],z_vals,zdir='z',c='b')
ax3.plot(zarr[:,0],zarr[:,1],z_vals,zdir='z',c='b')

for j in range(z_htxt.size):
    ltxt = z_htxt[j]+'_Q2_1000.txt'
    zarr[j] = np.loadtxt(ltxt)
    ax4.plot(zarr[j,0],zarr[j,1],zs=z_vals[j],zdir='z',c='r')
ax4.plot(zarr[:,0],zarr[:,1],z_vals,zdir='z',c='r')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
ax.view_init(elev=120,azim=-90)
ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y')
ax2.set_zlabel('Z')
ax2.set_zlim(0,1)
ax2.view_init(elev=120,azim=-90)
ax3.set_xlabel('X')
ax3.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3.set_zlabel('Z')
ax3.set_zlim(0,1)
ax3.view_init(elev=120,azim=-90)
ax4.set_xlabel('X')
ax4.set_ylabel('Y')
ax4.set_zlabel('Z')
ax4.set_zlim(0,1)
ax4.view_init(elev=120,azim=-90)
```

My code currently just pulls the x, y and z values from tables, then plots the 2D lines. I have tried using plot_surface() but to no avail since it tries to reference z values which I do not have data for. This might have been weird to explain, please let me know if I can clear anything up.

The shapes of my (x,y,z) arrays (zarr[:,0],zarr[:,1],z_vals[:]) are:
 (29,30), (29,30), (29,)  for x y and z respectively. If needed I can provide the full arrays.
Thanks!